# google.script.run doesn't run the function in Code.gs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a html box in my sheet with a button which should run a function.

I've simplified the code to isolate the problem and it seems like something is wrong with what I've made.

With this following code, the html output is created, the button react because the alert works, but the function inside code.gs doesn't run. Executions shows that htmlBox() is completed, but no trace of returnYes()

Could you help me please ?

Code.gs

```
function htmlBox(){

var htmlOutput = HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutputFromFile("box")
    .setWidth(200)
    .setHeight(50);
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, "Try to make work this button");

}

function returnYes(){

  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Test");
  var value = "yes!";
  
  ws.getRange(1, 1).setValue(value);
    
  }
```

box.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <div>
      <button id="btn">Run It!</button>
    </div>
    
    <script>
      
      document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",buttonClicked);
    
      function buttonClicked() {
      
      alert("Button clicked");
      google.script.run.returnYes();
            
      }

    </script>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. It works for me, using your exact same code. `yes!` is written to cell `A1` of sheet `Test`. You're not seeing `returnYes()` in the exeuctions tab, and also `yes!` not getting written to `A1`? Are you sure you are using this exact same code? I assume you are executing `htmlBox()` from the script editor?

Comment: Yes, I confirm it's the same code. I execute ```htmlBox()``` from the script editor. I don't see ```returnYes()``` in the executions tab, and nothing is written to A1. If I run ```returnYes()``` independently, it works.

I've to specify that I'm trying to run this from my professionnal GSuite account. Because you've been saying that it works for you, I've tried to reproduce it from a personnal google account and it works also. Is that possible that there are some restrictions on using this with a professional GSuite account?

Comment: I also used a G Suite account to test this, and it worked successfully, so this problem might be restricted to your account or your domain. Do you have access to Workspace support? I'd suggest you to [contact them](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?authuser=0).

Comment: When I try to contact them that give me the following message:
Your current account, xxx@xxx.com doesn't have permission to do these steps. To continue, switch to an administrator account. This will open the Google Admin console.

Comment: do you have a doGet function

Comment: You're right, I forgot the doGet function. By adding it in Code.gs it works. Thx @Baby_Boy

Comment: But now I don't understand how that works without the doGet function as explained in @lamblichus comment.

Comment: @Baby_Boy The dialog is already getting displayed, and the OP is running `htmlBox()` from the script editor. I don't see how a `doGet` function is necessary here.

Comment: But the OP said it worked sooo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's any news. The `doGet` function doesn't resolve the problem described above.

Today, I've tried to run `buttonClicked()` and it doesn't work although the `doGet` function.
The difference is that I've run the function from home. When it worked previously, I was at work and connected to my employer’s network. It seems that the function doesn't run when I try to launch it from my private network. So this problem might be restricted to my account or my domain, as suggested by @Iamblichus.

Thk @Iamblichus for your deduction. I don’t understand which restriction can prevent me from make work html and js file inside the same Apps Scripts project and I don't also unterstand what is the goal of a such restriction, but I know at least what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: THE FOLLOWING CODE DOESN'T RESOLVE THE PROBLEM DESCRIBED ABOVE

The problem was that a doGet function was missing in Code.gs.

By adding it that works now.

Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("box");

function htmlBox(){

var htmlOutput = HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutputFromFile("box")
    .setWidth(200)
    .setHeight(50);
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, "Try to make work this button");

}

function returnYes(){

  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Test");
  var value = "yes!";
  
  ws.getRange(1, 1).setValue(value);
    
  }
```

Thx to @Baby_Boy for the solution.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. The dialog was already getting displayed, and you are running `htmlBox()` from the script editor. I don't see how a `doGet` function is necessary here. The code works for me without adding a `doGet` function. `doGet` is for handling `GET` requests to a web app, not to display dialogs.

Comment: I agree and I have no idea why I need a ```doGet``` function on an account and not on the other... But it works.